# gmock: Why isn't EXPECT_CALL detecting the function call in my test?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

The text "callback called" from Callback() prints to console, but gmock fails the test saying that no callback happened. What am I doing wrong?

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass() { };
        virtual ~MyClass() { };
        void Callback() { printf("callback called\n"); };
};

class MyClassMock : public MyClass
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(Callback, void());
};

class Caller
{
public:
    Caller(MyClass *myClass) { m_myClass = *myClass; };
    void Call() { m_myClass.Callback(); };
private:
    MyClass m_myClass;
};

TEST(BasicTest, Positive)
{
    MyClassMock mock;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, Callback()).Times(1);

    Caller caller(&mock);
    caller.Call();
}
```

Comment: What's the exact output of the gmock error/warning? See [here](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Nonvirtual_Methods) how to mock non-virtual methods.

Comment: The error is just saying it expects 1 call and got none actual. I read the link you provided for nonvirtual functions, but it's not clear to me how I would adapt it for my code here...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your

```
void Callback();
```

method is not declared `virtual`. So you can't mock it that way with a simple derived mock class.

To cite from the [google-mock documentation](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Nonvirtual_Methods)

> Google Mock can mock non-virtual functions to be used in what we call hi-perf dependency injection.
>
> In this case, instead of sharing a common base class with the real class, your mock class will be unrelated to the real class, but contain methods with the same signatures.

The consequence is you have to realize this with a template. There's a concise example given at the documentation section linked from above.

---

Trying to *"translate"* their sample to your case, it should look like

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass() { };
        virtual ~MyClass() { };
        void Callback() { printf("callback called\n"); };
};

class MyClassMock {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(Callback, void());
};

template<class T>
class Caller {
public:
    Caller(T& myClass) : m_myClass(myClass) {}
    void Call() { m_myClass.Callback(); }
private:
    T& m_myClass;
};

TEST(BasicTest, Positive) {
    MyClassMock mock;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, Callback()).Times(1);

    Caller<MyClassMock> caller(mock);
    caller.Call();
}
```